# When should I use android SharedPreferences and when SQLite?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I understand `SharedPreferences` are ideal for small sets of key value pairs, but should I strive towards using `sqlite` is it more efficient (time and resources)?

Comment: Are saving a user login to show next time he opens the app for instance? Then you could go with sharedPreferences. Do you need rellations of data that depends on each other or this information has a potential to grow and need to have more info / rellations? Then go for Sqllite. Here is also a sqlite with repository pattern source code: 
https://github.com/grmaciel/android-repository-ormlite

Comment: @Gilson, thanks is there any other ORM recommended for SQL?

Comment: if you check the github link, the repository pattern was written over OrmLite which you can found more info here (http://ormlite.com/)